# java 8 stream.sorted with comparator in sets

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

**I have a set to sort (with Comparators) and I dont know which version to choose:**

**version 1:**

```
public static void sort(Set<User> users) {
    users = users.stream()
    .sorted(sort_gender.thenComparing(sort_age))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
}
```

**version 2:**

```
public static Set<User> sort(Set<User> users) {
    return users.stream()
    .sorted(sort_gender.thenComparing(sort_age))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
}
```

**version 3:**

```
public static void sort(Set<User> users) {
    users.stream()
    .sorted(sort_gender.thenComparing(sort_age))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

**version 4**

```
public static List<User> sort(Set<User> users){

List<User> list = new ArrayList<>(users);
list.sort(sort_gender.thenComparing(sort_age));
return list;
}
```

All versions sort a set and return the sorted set. I know, only linkedHashSet can preserve ordering.

**Which one should I choose**, I only want to sort the input properties users and return it, so is version 1 the best for that case? (For all cases, I want the references of input users be the same as for output users.)

**EDIT: I think, I will choose version 4.**

Comment: What is `sort_gender` in this case? A Comparator, I guess?

Comment: You know that version 1 wouldn't "return" anything, don't you? `users = whatever` will reassign the parameter but that won't be visible from the outside. The other versions won't compile as the return type `void` won't fit. Besides that as you set only `LinkedHashSet` keeps the order so it would probably be version 2. (And btw, those 3 versions aren't that different anyways, so in the future just pick the one you like - provided they work correctly).

Comment: probably `v3` because your return type is `void` :p change it to `Set<User>`

Comment: Sorry for that, I changed the return type.

Comment: Test your code. Testing it will make it obvious what to use, because two out of the three versions don't do anything.

Comment: Why don't you write a simple test for that code and pick the one which will works better? What about `SortedSet`/`NavigableSet` interface family?

Comment: @JBNizet, they do something: they make the world around us a little warmer, just that tiny bit.

Comment: I only want to achieve this: sort the set-> the caller needs it, because to iterate through the sorted set. Nothing more. This should be achieved with the best performance. I can also convert set to list and sort the list and iterate through that list, Would this be better?

Comment: @nimo23, For just iterating right after, `List` is indeed probably better ,because that's what the defining characteristic of a list is: it's ordered. Most implementations are also lighter than implementations of `Set`s. For storing result somewhere where it matters that this is a set, one of the `Set` insterfaces is better. For clearly stating what it is, use `SortedSet` or `NavigableSet`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would add a 4-th method (if you are OK to change that method to return the sorted `Set`)

```
 users.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing...)))
```

I would return a `SortedSet` to make it explicit for the caller that this is actually sorted.

If not you could do:

```
SortedSet<User> sorted = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing...)
sorted.addAll(users);
```

Comment: I can also use: public static LinkedHashSet<User> sort(Set<User> users) {...} to make it explicit..or?

Comment: @nimo23 The potential benefit of `TreeSet` is that if you add an element to the returned set, the set will remain ordered, while with `LinkedHashSet`, the element will be returned at the end when the set is iterated. But as you say, `LinkedHashSet` has better performance.

Comment: "I would return a TreeSet to make it explicit for the caller that this is actually sorted." Hm, I don't know about that. You're making it hard to change implementation later on. I'd just add an appropriate guarantee to the JavaDoc.

Comment: @nimo23, 1. There is a `SortedSet<T>` interface, which `TreeSet<T>` is a part of, and is even better to display intent. 2. Saying "performance of A is better than B" without stating: (a) which performance we're talking here and (b) what the set is supposed to be used after - is not very useful.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov good point, `SortedSet`... how did I forget about this? :| thank u

Comment: The call is already explicit: "myUsers = Sorter.sort(myUsers)". But I must redeclare myUsers with the output of Sorter.sort. With typical arraylist, I can do only: users.sort(myComparator); without redeclaring the users..which is much better..

Comment: @nimo23 right, but what if you pass that along again? Someone receiving a `LinkedHashSet` might not know that it's actually sorted

Comment: @Eugene, stream part here is arguably unnecessary, I think, because nothing we'd do with a stream would convince TreeSet to not revalidate the sorting and sort the second time (zing to API developers: `TreeSet.of(SortedStream)`), thus reducing the meaning of a stream to just a fancy `for` loop (and it's a lot heavier than a loop).

Comment: @M.Prokhorov agreed, I only posted it thinking this was an exercise for the OP

Comment: @Prokhorov so you suggest to use "SortedSet" for such cases instead of the stream()-solution? Does it perform better?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov often overlooked, there is [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/NavigableMap.html), introduced in Java 6, extending `SortedSet` and usually preferable.

Answer (score 5):

Version one does effectively nothing. You are changing the reference of the parameter `users` but not altering the set which is passed as an argument and not returning anything.

Version two works correctly.

Version three is attempting to store a sorted set in a set that does not maintain order. It's effectively no different than returning the set that you're given. From the JavaDoc for [`toSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--):

> There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or
>   thread-safety of the Set returned

Comment: And version 3 has the same problem as version 1 anyway.